# Linq to get a list of files by ascending order from a directory, based on their name C#

Tags: c#, linq, file

I have a directory that contains several files, some `.txt` and some `.sql`. let's just focus on the `.sql` files.

These files contain sql statements that I need to parse and later execute, but the files are named like **`1_ORCA_3_9_56.sql`** and **`99_ACT_VERSAO.sql`** or any other name, the only important part is the number with which they start wince it will dictated the order that I need to execute them.
I've made a function using Linq that will give me a list by ascending order of all files (I actually retrieve their full name/path, thats what I need) but the query returns me 0 items.

**This is the function**:

```
 public List<string> ListaDeFicheiros(string Directoria)
        {
            Global.Erro = "";
            Global.ErroGrave = false;
            string caminho = "";

            var Paths = new  List<string>();
            Version version = null;
            var lastVersion = new DirectoryInfo(Directoria).EnumerateFiles()
                        .Where(d => d.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".sql"))
                        .Select(d => new { Directory = d.Directory, Token = d.Name.Split('_') })
                        //.Select(d => new { Directory = d, Token = d.Name.Split('_') })
                        .Where(x => x.Token.Length == 3 && Version.TryParse(x.Token[2], out version))
                        .Select(x => new { Directory = x.Directory, Date = x.Token[1], Version = version })
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
                        .Select(x => x.Directory.FullName);
            Paths = lastVersion.ToList();
            return Paths;
        }
```

Any help would be aprecciated, any questions just make a comment and I will try to answer as detailed as I can.

> Have in mind that I just need to get the .sql files and ignore any other extension.

Comment: You can enumeratefiles with just *.sql and save that first .where line, you then test for token length ==3, but in one of your examples, it wouldnt be 3 as 1_orca_3_9_56 would give you 5, so you want to test if equal or more than 2 really by the looks of it.. you then try parsing token 2, surely its token 0 the first number?  as you then also take token 1 as your version which would be orca or act in your examples.. this could be why you dont get any results.

Comment: @BugFinder Im realyl not that handy with Linq, I still couldnt get a good grasp on it, an example would be great. But I got the idea, if the length is 5 I cant only test it for 3. Can I just .split by _ and order by that number?

Comment: its not the linq you got wrong, its the actual code of working.... IMHO

Comment: @BugFinder the only problem with it its what you mentioned? what would you change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) to enumerate only "*.sql" files. Then I use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) and create an anonymous type that contains the full path and the parsed version.

To parse the version I use [`Path.GetFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename) to get the file name without path. If the file name does not have the correct format, I set the version to `-1`.

Then I [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) for valid versions, [sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) the enumeration by that version and return a list of the sorted file names:

```
List<string> Paths = Directory.GetFiles(Directoria, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
    Select(f => {
        int version;
        string[] parts = Path.GetFileName(f).Split('_');
        if (parts.Length < 1 || !int.TryParse(parts[0], out version))
            version = -1;
        return new {File = f, Version = version};
    }).
    Where(f => f.Version > -1).
    OrderBy(f => f.Version).
    Select(f => f.File).ToList();
```

Comment: I actually need the file path. thats the most importent part of it. I think you just change it to Directory.Fullname()

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName I'm not sure what you mean. You can easily get the path via `Path.GetDirectoryName()`, but wouldn't that always simply be `Directoria`?

Comment: It still retrieves 0 items on the list

Comment: Hm, works for me. Seems you need to debug it (maybe break the code in single operations for this) to find out if files are enumerated and the name parsing works correctly. Maybe something's wrong with your `Directoria` parameter or access rights on the files.

Comment: this is the path I pas: C:\cdp-si\_temp\setup19\UPDATE_20080312_3.80.0\scripts
Allt the files are inside that directory . I've changed the Path.FullName() to Path.GetDirecotryName(). And its not a permission problem

Comment: It woker. actually you cant use Path.GetDirectoryName() for some reason didnt worked for me. but I've changed it to your original answer and it worked. thank you